# How to write a filter to remove a form field (WordPress)

Tags: filters

I want to remove a form field. How do I write a filter hook to remove it?

[image: Screenhot]

Comment: Assuming a filter even exists, which it may not, then the specifics depend almost entirely on the theme/plugin you’re using for this form. You will need to ask its author, since 3rd-party plugins are off topic here.

Comment: Thanks for the information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution for this is

[data-handler-id="job_extra_fast_delivery_price"] {
display: none;
}